# My loop to grab number of results within an array in swift is not working

Tags: arrays, swift

Greetings dear fans and programmers of the Swift language. I have tried to formulate an algorithm number of times an element shows up within an array with a for loop, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My code is as follows:

```
else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GreenCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            for item in theModel.userAnswer {
                numOfCoincidences[item] = (numOfCoincidences[item] ?? 0) + 1
            }

            for (numLangs, value) in numOfCoincidences {
                txtSummary = "#languages spoken: \(numLangs)"
                txtSummary2 = "# of People: \(value)"

            }

            cell.textLabel?.text = txtSummary
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = txtSummary2
```

I am trying to display this information in a table Cell but it is not working. I thought that my algorithm was spot on. Any suggestions?

I'm getting the following output: I have a navigation controller in effect where I input data on one screen and it outputs the data on a table. It's a bit of a survey where I prompt the user to enter their name and the number of languages spoken. I'm using an MVC programming methodology.

so in the model, here is the code:

```
import Foundation

class Model {


    var userName = [String]()
    var userAnswer = [String]()
    var userInfo = [String]()
    var name:String
    var answer:String

    init(){
        self.name = ""
        self.answer = ""

    }

    func addUserInfo(name:String, answer:String) -> Void {
        userName.append(name)
        userAnswer.append(answer)
    }

}
```

In the input screen, I have 2 text boxes that prompt for username and number of languages spoken. So on the output screen, if 2 people speak 4 languages, the output should reflect that, but it's not. If 1 person speaks 3 languages, it should display that and so on. The output is coming out completely incorrectly. Here is the for the data entry code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = Model()

    @IBOutlet var txtName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var lblStatus: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var txtAnswer: UITextField!
    @IBAction func btnAnswer(sender: UIButton) {
        model.answer = txtAnswer.text!
        model.name = txtName.text!
        if ((txtName.text)! == "" || (txtAnswer.text)!  == "") {
            lblStatus.text = "Name and answer are both required"
        }else if model.userName.contains(model.name) {
            lblStatus.text = "Answer already recorded for \(model.name)"
        } else {
            model.addUserInfo(model.name, answer: model.answer)
            lblStatus.text = "Ok, \(model.name) answered \(model.answer)"
        }
        txtAnswer.text = ""
        txtName.text = ""
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toReesultsController" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! TableViewController
            vc.theModel = self.model

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


}
```

The code for the table to display the data inputted from the data entry screen is presented in a table as shown below:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var theModel = Model()
    var numOfCoincidences:[String:Int] = [:]
    var txtSummary:String = ""
    var txtSummary2:String = ""
    var greatest:Int = 0

   /* override func viewDidLoad() {
        for index in 0..<theModel.userName.count {

        }
    }*/

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return theModel.userAnswer.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            return theModel.userAnswer.count
        } else if section == 2{
            return theModel.userAnswer.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0 {
            return "Answer Log"
        } else if section == 1 {
            return "Summary"
        } else if section == 2 {
            return "Top Answers"
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell! = nil

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BlueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(theModel.userName[indexPath.row]):\(theModel.userAnswer[indexPath.row])"
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GreenCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            for item in theModel.userAnswer {
                numOfCoincidences[item] = (numOfCoincidences[item] ?? 0) + 1
            }

            for (numLangs, value) in numOfCoincidences {
                txtSummary = "#languages spoken: \(numLangs)"
                txtSummary2 = "# of People: \(value)"

            }

            cell.textLabel?.text = txtSummary
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = txtSummary2



        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrangeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            greatest = 0
            for index in 0..<theModel.userAnswer.count {

                if Int(theModel.userAnswer[index])! > greatest {
                    greatest = Int(theModel.userAnswer[index])!
                }
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Answer with most votes is \(greatest) languages spoken."

        }



        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Matt, what do you mean by that statement?

Comment: Show your input and what you expect as output. That way we can run it in playground and give you a solid answer.

Comment: Ok will do, is it ok if I show picture/video input/output to demonstrate the app?

Comment: If you use a picture, how am I going to copy and paste so I can test? I will have to type the data from your picture.  So, no. A picture is a bad idea.

Comment: Noted one moment Ryan

Comment: Ryan, I have gone ahead and did what you requested. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking for something like this:- input `[2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]` should product output:- `[2:3, 3:4]`.

Comment: got it so input is like this: name: a, #langs spoken: 3, name: b, #langs spoken: 3, name: c, #langs spoken: 2, #name: d, #langs spoken: 1. Output on the other hand is more like this num langs spoken: 5 num of people who speak 5 languages: 1, num langs spoken 5: num of people who speak 2, etc. etc. not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is if two people speak 5 languages, that would be displayed in the second part of the table, if 3 people speak 1 language that result will also be returned, but the resulting output is not showing that. Is that detailed enough? Sorry if it is vague. Please don't downrate my OP :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109209/discussion-between-ryantxr-and-linuxn00b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have shared, and making some assumptions on your input this seems to do what you want.

If each item is a dictionary with the keys shown below. Then you would walk through the array and get the number of languages spoken by the person. I chose to define that as a number(Int) since that is what it really is.

This is almost the same as your original code so I have to conclude that your idea was correct, but your implementation was missing something.

Assuming this is your input:

```
 let a = [["name":"carla", "langs" : 3], ["name":"scott", "langs" : 3], ["name":"brad", "langs" : 1], ["name":"cynthia", "langs":2]]

var numOfCoincidences = [Int: Int]()
for item in a {
    let numLangs = item["langs"] as! Int
    numOfCoincidences[numLangs] = (numOfCoincidences[numLangs] ?? 0) + 1

}

var txtSummary = ""
var txtSummary2 = ""
for (numLangs, value) in numOfCoincidences {
    // You should also note that you are overwriting values here.
    txtSummary = "#languages spoken: \(numLangs)"
    txtSummary2 = "# of People: \(value)"
    print(txtSummary)
    print(txtSummary2)
}
numOfCoincidences
```

Output:

```
// key := number of languages spoken
// value := number of people who speak that many languages
[2: 1, 3: 2, 1: 1]
```

You do have a problem in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

After you loop through all the data, you do this:

```
        cell.textLabel?.text = txtSummary
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = txtSummary2
```

Therefore, every cell is going to have the last values from the loop.